# Cordova: Android app showing blank page

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, apache-cordova

I want to convert a website into an android app using Apache Cordova and visual studio 2015. Below is my index.html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>Zoggle</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script>
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  function onDeviceReady() {
    //navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    if (navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
      networkError()
    } else {
      loadApp()
    }
  }

  function loadApp() {
    navigator.app.loadUrl("http://zoggle.zolmeister.com")
  }

  function networkError() {
    navigator.notification.alert('Zoggle requires an internet connection')
    var $net = document.createElement('div')
    $net.innerHTML = 'Zoggle requires an internet connection'
    document.body.appendChild($net)
  }
  </script>

  <style>
  body {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #23252e;
    color: #01ced3;
    text-align: center;
  }
  div {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code, it shows me a blank black page. I want to load the web page the link is given..Please Help.

Comment: You'd better issue it on [phonegap's github page](https://github.com/phonegap/).

Comment: Have you tried with Inappbrowser plugin
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

Answer (score -1):

You can use Inappbrowser Plugin to load the website in your app

http://www.plugreg.com/plugin/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/